# MVC3 / EF CustomValidator two fields in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, data-annotations, customvalidator

Using MVC3 and EF4.1 how do I validate on client and server more than one field in my view model?

I have a start date text box (that can be modified) and I have the original start date in a hidden field.  When the user submits the form I want to check that the modied start date is no more than one month either side of the original start date.

I can't figure out how this can be done with DataAnnotation and CustomValidation (or maybe I'm going down the wrong road)?  This is an example of whay I've been working with:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Metadata.MyUserMetaData))]
public partial class MyUser
{
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }    
}
```

Partial Class

```
public class MyUserMetaData
{
    [CustomValidation(typeof(AmendedStartDate), "amendedstartdate", ErrorMessage = "Invalid date."]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; };

    public DateTime OriginalStartDate { get; set; };
}
```

Custom Validator

```
public class AmendedStartDate : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // How do I get multiple field values from object value?
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(Modelmetadata metadate, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
        ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "amendedstartdate"
        };

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

I know I've still to add jQuery to the view for this validator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asked in [MVC custom validation: compare two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025198/mvc3-custom-validation-compare-two-dates) has an example of a validator which compares to a second value in the model.  That should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using data annotations implement `IValidatableObject` on your model class - it is simpler and much more clear in scenarios with cross validation.

If you still want to use `ValidationAttribute` you have two parameters in the `IsValid` method:

- `value` represents validated value of the property where the attribute is assigned
- `context` is context in which the property is validated. It also contains `ObjectInstance` and `ObjectType` properties to access the whole model and its type so you can cast the instance and access other properties.

Comment: Thank you Ladislav. I accepted @counsellorben answer as I was already down that road, but will definately look at your solution the next time.