# ASP.NET MVC implement custom validator use IClientValidatable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I ask similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278883/asp-net-mvc-run-custom-validators-in-client-side/8280323#8280323) but in this question I use another implementation, exactly [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025198/mvc3-custom-validation-compare-two-dates) the following codes show my implementations:

**Model:**

```
public class Department {

    public long Id { get; set; }

    [IsDateAfter("Date2", true, ErrorMessage = "O My")]
    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date2 { get; set; }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }

}
```

**Custom Validator:**

```
public sealed class IsDateAfter : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable {

    private readonly string testedPropertyName;
    private readonly bool allowEqualDates;

    public IsDateAfter(string testedPropertyName, bool allowEqualDates = false)
  {
        this.testedPropertyName = testedPropertyName;
        this.allowEqualDates = allowEqualDates;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext
 validationContext) {
        var propertyTestedInfo = 
validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.testedPropertyName);
        if (propertyTestedInfo == null) {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("unknown property
 {0}", this.testedPropertyName));
        }

        var propertyTestedValue =
 propertyTestedInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (value == null || !(value is DateTime)) {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        if (propertyTestedValue == null || !(propertyTestedValue is
 DateTime)) {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        // Compare values
        if ((DateTime)value >= (DateTime)propertyTestedValue) {
            if (this.allowEqualDates) {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            if ((DateTime)value > (DateTime)propertyTestedValue) {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }

        return new
 ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> 
GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context) {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule {
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessageString,
            ValidationType = "isdateafter"
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters["propertytested"] =
 this.testedPropertyName;
        rule.ValidationParameters["allowequaldates"] =
 this.allowEqualDates;
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

**Script:**

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
'isdateafter', ['propertytested', 'allowequaldates'], function (options) {
    options.rules['isdateafter'] = options.params;
    options.messages['isdateafter'] = options.message;
});
$.validator.addMethod("isdateafter", function (value, element, params) {
alert(params.propertytested);
var startdatevalue = $('input[name="' + params.propertytested + '"]').val();
if (!value || !startdatevalue) return true;
return (params.allowequaldates) ? Date.parse(startdatevalue) <= Date.parse(value) :
 Date.parse(startdatevalue) < Date.parse(value);
}, '');
```

**And My _Layout page (Master page)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
 </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript">
 </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript">
 </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript">
 </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery.IsDateAfter.js")" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="title">
            <h1>
                My MVC Application</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="logindisplay">
            @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
        </div>
        <div id="menucontainer">
            <ul id="menu">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Departments", "Index", "Department")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

of course in Edit And Create View pages the other script source are as following:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**A part of Create Page Dom:**

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Department</legend>
<div class="editor-label">
<label for="Date1">Date1</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
<input id="Date1" class="text-box single-line valid" type="text" value="" name="Date1"
 data-val-required="The Date1 field is required." data-val-isdateafter-
 propertytested="Date2" data-val-isdateafter-allowequaldates="False" data-val-
isdateafter="O My" data-val="true">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-
  for="Date1"></span>
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
<label for="Date2">Date2</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
<input id="Date2" class="text-box single-line valid" type="text" value="" name="Date2"
 data-val-required="The Date2 field is required." data-val="true">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-
for="Date2"></span>
</div>
```

I try All of implementation be the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025198/mvc3-custom-validation-compare-two-dates) but that not work in client side and need to postback, I don't have any other implementation for example register in global.asax 
like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278883/asp-net-mvc-run-custom-validators-in-client-side/8280323#8280323), Does any one know about it? I really confused, I tried 2 way but none of them give the true answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have messed up your script inclusions. In your _Layout you have included the following scripts in that order:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery.IsDateAfter.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now obviously `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.js` represents the same script, the first being the minified version. But since you haven't included the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script (this is done much later in your view), your custom `jQuery.IsDateAfter.js` script will contain errors since it will not know about the `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters` object that you are using. So here's how the scripts in your layout should look:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You could also add your custom `jQuery.IsDateAfter.js` script to the layout at the end if you wish in case it is used in many views and if not you could add it to the view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery.IsDateAfter.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That's the only script you should have in the view. You should remove any other `jquery.*` script inclusions from  your Edit And Create View pages.

Remark: you will also notice that I have removed all `Microsoft*.js` scripts from your Layout. They are obsolete and should no longer be used in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: I followed this and can see the validation error messages while i edit the form which is great. One weird thing about it, that it doesn't stop form post even having invalid fields with proper validation error messages however server does recognize ModelState.IsValid as false... is this normal behavior or am I missing something?