# How can I create a list of reserved words and then test against them when a user registers using asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am an MVC C# newbie.

I have a project which is using the built-in simple membership features of .net. I have that all working fine. I do however want to prevent a user from choosing certain usernames when registering which are NOT in the database already, such as swear words (of which I have been using plenty today).

I want to test against this list both in an ajax call and on submit. What is the proper way of going about this? I already have the system checking for usernames in use from the DB with no problem.

I have added a list called ReservedWords to the RegisterModel, but I just do not know where or how even to populate it so that it is available to the 2 controllers (async and post).

The Model looks like this:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public List<ReservedWord> ReservedWords { get; set; }
}
```

Am I supposed to populate it in the model file or in the controller? In either case can you please provide a sample?

The controller code is here for both the async and post backs:

```
 // POST: /Account/doesUserNameExist async

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string UserName)
    {
        var user = Membership.GetUser(UserName);
        return Json(user == null);
    }


 // POST: /Account/Register

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, Request.Form["RoleName"]);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!!!!

---

### Update

So I followed the advice to create a custom validation attribute and it works great on submit. Thanks! Is there a way to get it to work with the client side validation? I have a similar custom validation attribute which compares two fields and makes sure they're not equal. I followed that code but no luck. Here is the code now:

```
public class BlackListWordAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string defaultErrorMessage = "{0} cannot use forbidden word.";

    private readonly List<string> blackListedWords = new List<string>();

    public BlackListWordAttribute()
        : base(defaultErrorMessage)
    {
        //populate from database or text file with cache dependency on either
        blackListedWords.Add("bananas");
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (blackListedWords.Any(x => x.ToLower() == value.ToString().ToLower()))
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName),
            //This is the name of the method added to the jQuery validator method (must be lower case)
            ValidationType = "blacklistword"
        };

    }
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would at using custom validation. If you change your mode to

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [BlackListWord]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then the custom validation attribute could look something like:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
    public class BlackListWordValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
        private readonly List<string>  blackListedWords = new List<string>();

        public BlackListWordValidationAttribute() {
            //populate from database or text file with cache dependency on either
            blackListedWords.Add("bananas");
        }
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {
            if(value!=null) {
                if (blackListedWords.Any(x => x.ToLower() == value.ToString().ToLower()))
                    return new ValidationResult(@"Cannot use black listed word.");
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

You can store the blacklist either in the database or a file or xml or whatever.

Then you can add client side validation as well. To help with that look at using something like this [Filthy List](http://www.thefilthylist.com/pages/services.aspx) which you can access via a web service.

EDIT/UPDATE No 2:

As requested by the question asker. The best way to make the code available to both "async and post backs" is to create a string extension method. For instance,

```
public static class StringExtension {
        public static bool IsUserNameAllowed(this string value) {
    List<ReservedWord> ReservedWords = GetReservedWordsFromPersistantMedium();

    return ReservedWords.All(x => x.Word.ToLower() != value.ToLower());
    }
}
```

The above class to be put either a referenced project or extensions folder with web project.

Then you can just call

```
model.UserName.IsUserNameAllowed() or userName.IsUserNameAllowed()
```

For example:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string UserName)
{
    if !(UserName.IsUserNameAllowed())
    {
        return Json(new { ErrorMessage="An error has occured"});
    }
    var user = Membership.GetUser(UserName);
    return Json(user == null);
}
```

in either scenarios

Comment: Thanks! This totally makes sense. I will likely implement this. But out of curiosity I would like to see if someone can answer using my methodology, please. I want to know why I am so block headed...

Comment: So I got the server side working but I cannot seem to get the client side to work.

Comment: sorry. Where exactly would the method go? And where would the caller go? Learning by example here.

Comment: You rock! I will try that. And just for my own edification, is there a reason why the IClientValidatable client side code does not work in my previous validation extension?

Comment: @Julian it's hard to tell have a look at this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284207/asp-net-mvc-implement-custom-validator-use-iclientvalidatable) question

Comment: Thanks that worked. I will ask a new question why the IClientValidatable approach would not client side validate.