# validation on mvc dropdown values?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have created 5 dropdowns in mvc razor view using `foreach`. I need to do validation if same value gets selected in more than one dropdown in jquery.

I can easily do it using the dropdown `id` but what if I have more number of dropdown which is created dynamically?

Is there any generic code/way to do this?

```
   </div>
 @Html.DropDownList("drdId"+count, new SelectList((ViewData["MYList"] as List<MYDATA>).Select(t => new { Value = t.Id, Text = t.Name }), "Value", "Text"))
                    </div>
```

I tried like

function test(){
        var arr = new Array($("#count1").val(),$("#count2").val(), $("#count3").val(), $("#count4").val());
        for(var i=0; i

> how do I make array arr dynamic for more number of dropdowns?

Comment: Client-side or server-side validation?

Comment: Client-side obv. You can create a custom validator which compares the selectlist values. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284207/asp-net-mvc-implement-custom-validator-use-iclientvalidatable)

Comment: @markpsmith Example is not so clear any other thread ?

Comment: Do a search for IClientValidatable, there are lots of tutorials available, e.g. [http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: you can add class to each of the dropdowns and then check them by loop.. some html will help,if you could provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following logic. Lets suppose each dropdown has the class "testClass":

```
 function checkSelect(ref) {
            var len = $(".testClass").length;
            var count=0;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if ($(".testClass:eq(" + i + ") option:selected").val() !="0" && $(".testClass:eq(" + i + ") option:selected").val() == $(ref).val())
                    count++;
            }
            if (count < 2)
                return true;
            else {
                $(ref).val("0");
                return false;
            }

         }
```

Now call this function on change of dropdown:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".testClass").on("change", function () {
       if (!checkSelect($(this)))
          alert("Can not select duplicate");
      });
 });
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I also tried like following check updated question
how do I make it dynamic for all dropdowns?

Comment: You just need to add the "testClass" to every dropdown. And then the above code will help you.