# pass prop as param to another prop custom attribute c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, model-validation

i want to pass a property as a parameter to another property custom attribute but i can't because its not static 
Model ex :

```
public class model1
{
     public DateTime param1 { get; set; }
     [CustomAttribute (param1)]
     public string param2 { get; set; }
}

public class CustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly DateTime _Date;
    public CustomAttribute(DateTime date)
    {
        _Date= date;
    }
}
```

because i want to make a custom validation between this two attributes .

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/7026441/9695286

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributes are not stored as executable code, so there are significant limitations on the kind of data you can include in them.

Basically, you must stick with base types: strings, numbers, dates. Everything that can be a constant.

Fortunately, you can use a bit of reflection and the [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) operator:

```
public class model1
{
     public DateTime param1 { get; set; }
     [CustomAttribute (nameof(param1))]
     public string param2 { get; set; }
}

public class CustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _propertyName;
    public CustomAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        _propertyName = propertyName;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the validation logic should reside outside the attribute's code.

The needed ingredients for the validation will be [Type.GetProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.7.2),  [PropertyInfo.GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2), and [MemberInfo.GetCustomAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_CustomAttributeExtensions_GetCustomAttribute__1_System_Reflection_MemberInfo_System_Boolean_).

If you need a complete example and care to better explain the use case, let me know.

Comment: Then, if your problem is solved, upvote the answer (with the up arrow) and accept it as the proper answer (selecting the green mark).